# Is it possible to initialize a final variable after declaring..?

Tags: java, syntax, final

Is this even possible, few argue its possible and i saw it here too [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677595/initialize-final-variable-before-constructor-in-java).. but when i personally tried it gives me compile time errors..

i mean this,

```
Class A{
    private final String data;

    public A(){
        data = "new string";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the compile time error that you are getting ?

Comment: Maybe your compile time error relates to upper-case 'Class'. The rest is perfectly fine and must compile.

Comment: **The blank final field data may not have been initialized**... this is what i get..

Comment: If you are sick, do you send your wife to the doctor? Show us the real code.

Comment: This code doesn't compile due to the Class in upper-case. So this is not the real code, or at least there is an other compile error, as already said by the other comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Class is written with small case c. Otherwise your code is perfectly fine (except for identation):

```
public class A {
   private final String data;

   public A() {
      data = "new string";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize a final instance variable after declaration.

- If it's static, you have to initialize it in a static initialization
  block.
- Else, you have to initialize it in the constructor.

The problem with the code you've posted is the uppercase `C`. It should have been `class` as Boris pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that you are having more than one constructor, in that case you must initialize the final instance field in each of those constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Like Boris suggested the code is fine. What you can not do though, would be to assign a second value to the final variable data. `data = "another string";` will not compile, since data is final and thus its value can not be changed after the initialization.

```
public class A {
   private final String data;

   public A() {
      data = "new string";
      data = "another string";
   }
}
```